# Помогите с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь составить регулярку, которая бы захватила первые 8 строк, а строки 9-14 - нет. Проверяю с помощью https://regex101.com/.

```
/^(складен(ою|а))?\s?(випадков(ою|а))?\sподі(єю|я)$/gm
```

Строки для проверки:

```
складеною випадковою подією
складена випадкова подія
складеною подією
складена подія
випадковою подією
випадкова подія
випадковою складеною подією
випадкова складена подія

складеною складеною подією
складена складена подія
випадковою випадковою подією
випадкова випадкова подія
подією
подія
```

Мой пример захватывает 6 строк. А как сделать, чтобы захватывал 7 и 8 - не знаю. Думал сделать такое, но не знаю как:

```
/^(складен(ою|а)\s)?(випадков(ою|а)\s)?(поді(єю|я))$/gm
  └──────1──────┘ └───────3──────┘ └────5────┘
1 3 5
1   5
3   5
3 1 5
```

Comment: Объясните подробнее по какому принципу нужно захватывать текст, а по какому принципу его не нужно захватывать. Прочтите секцию  **Как задать вопрос про регулярные выражения** здесь http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/info

Comment: Пишу программу на Qt. В нем реализован класс регулярных выражений http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexp.html. Пользователю задается вопрос. Он вводит ответ в QLineEdit. По клику на кнопку мы проверяем ответ с заранее заданным шаблоном ответа (регуляркой). Если совпадает - пользователь ответил правильно.

Comment: Как Вы думаете: Ваш ответ отвечает на вопрос "по какому принципу нужно захватывать текст, а по какому принципу его не нужно захватывать" ?

Comment: @ReinRaus, Мне казалось, я привел ясный пример того, какие строки должны быть захвачены, а какие нет. Пожалуйста, отметьте вариант BOPOH как правильный, и закройте тему как решенную.

Comment: Принцип не ясен. Почему нужно захватить именно те строки, почему те не надо захватить ? Прочтите свой вопрос внимательно. В нем не понятно что нужно делать. Почему кто-то должен **догадываться** по какому принципу нужно делать отбор ?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще неправильный подход к решению. Надо так:

```
^((^| )(.)(?!.* \3)[^ ]+){2,}$
```

Проверка:

```
"складеною випадковою подією\n\
складена випадкова подія\n\
складеною подією\n\
складена подія\n\
випадковою подією\n\
випадкова подія\n\
випадковою складеною подією\n\
випадкова складена подія\n\
\
складеною складеною подією\n\
складена складена подія\n\
випадковою випадковою подією\n\
випадкова випадкова подія\n\
подією\n\
подія".split("\n").map(function(s) {
  return /^((^| )(.)(?!.* \3)[^ ]+){2,}$/.test(s);
})

// [true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false]
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, Вы используете php? Просто не могу проверить результат. И, судя по смыслу Вашей регулярки, Вы проверяете третье слово и то, есть ли перед ним одно или два неповторяющихся слов. Я хочу проверить именно правильность ввода с заданным шаблоном. А если пользователь введет "Мама мыла раму" или любые три слова, Ваша регулярка пропустит ввод, так?

Comment: Это js (т.е. можно скопировать в консоль и посмотреть результат). Если надо изменить ваш вариант, то можно так: `/^((складен|випадков)(ою|а))\s(?!\1)((складен|випадков)(ою|а))?\s?поді(єю|я)$/` Но тогда будет пропускать `складеною складена подія`. Поэтому лучше сначала ответить @ReinRaus

Comment: 1. Нет, это javascript, а не php. Открываешь консоль браузера и проверяешь. 2. Нет, я проверяю, что строка состоит из двух или более слов, и первые буквы всех слов различны. 3. А где собственно шаблон? Конкатенируем тогда все возможные строки и проверяем. 4. Я нашёл наиболее общую закономерность, какую смог. Вопрос очень похож на вопрос из какого-нибудь regex golf задания.

Comment: @Qwertiy, кстати, мой вариант и для grep'а работает (а ваш нет). Не знаете что в вашей регулярке такого особенного? Мне че-то кажется, что у grep и js разница в обработке `(?!.* \3)`

Comment: @BOPOH, про grep не в курсе.

Comment: @BOPOH, прекрасный пример! Делает то, что хотелось. Но да, тогда пропускает вариант `складеною складена подія`. Кстати, спасибо, что указали на эту неточность.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за подсказку про консоль. Проверил, Ваша регулярка выдает `false` для вариантов `складеною складена подія` и `випадковою випадкова подією`, но `true` при `Среда пятница четверг`.

Comment: @Cirran, в моем примере уберите первую пару скобок и будет работать (т.е. надо `/^(складен|випадков)(ою|а)\s(?!\1)((складен|випадков)(ою|а))?\s?поді(єю|я)$/`)

Comment: @BOPOH, Ура! Я чуть изменил Ваш вариант `/^((складен|випадков)(ою|а))\s(?!\1)((складен|випадков)\3)?\s?поді(єю|я)$/` и теперь не пропускает варианты `складеною складена подія` `випадковою випадкова подією`. Как отметить Ваш ответ правильным?